# jQuery function calling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have a callback call a function inside $(document).ready(..)

How do I call a function from outside this?

Like for example:

```
$(document).ready( function(foo) {
   var bar = function() { ... };
});

// How do I call bar() from here?
```

Comment: Are you looking to call bar() from within $(document).ready() or outside of it (where you put the comment)?

See jdangel's answer for inside.

Comment: This seems counter intuitive. Why wouldn't you declare the function outside the $(document).ready() and then call the function from within the $(document).ready()?

Comment: @Mark.. outside of it...

Comment: That was what I was wondering (if LB missed the obvious) so I figured I'd check

Comment: @jdangel, because I may need to generate the function from jQuery

Comment: I see, however if you don't call the function until the document is ready, it doesn't matter what you put inside the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends on how you want to scope things. If you just want bar to be in the global scope, then just do this:

```
$(document).ready( function(foo) {
   var bar = function() { ... };
   window.bar = bar;
});
```

Remember, in JavaScript the only code blocks that have scope are functions, so variables declared in `if{}`, `while{}`, and other types of code blocks are global to whatever function they are a part of, unless they are not declared.

If you use a variable without declaring it, that is the same as doing:

```
// Both of these variables have global scope, assuming
// 'bar' was never declared anywhere above this
window.foo = "Hello World!";
bar = "Hello World!";
```

So the example above could be a line shorter by doing:

```
$(document).ready( function(foo) {
   window.bar = function() { ... };
});
```

Comment: this has the same effect as simply omitting the "var" before "bar"

Comment: While this would work, how is this different from removing the $(document).ready() entirely and simply declaring this outside: /* $(document).ready( function(foo) { */ window.bar = function() { ... }; /* });*/

Answer (score 2):

Don't declare everything inside of the ready function

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  ...
  bar();
});

function bar() {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare bar outside of your ready function.  It will be global then.

```
var bar;

$(document).ready( function(foo) {
   bar = function() { ... };
});
```

Comment: Isn't it global even without that declaration at the top?

Comment: @Nosredna: implicit globals killed my parents

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `bar()` from the outside, why don't you just declare it on the outside, passing it whatever parameters you need from the inner scope?

```
function bar(baz, qix) { ...};

$(document).ready(function(foo) {
        bar(whatever, whatnot);
        });
bar(something, else);
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comment, maybe you want to do something like this. Use `myUtilities` to minimize global namespace pollution if you're going to want to be accessing things inside and outside your `ready`.

```
var myUtilities={};

$(document).ready( function(foo) {
   myUtilities.bar = function() { ... };
});

// How do I call bar() from here?
a = myUtilities.bar();
```

Sorry, untested. Might be a dumb syntax mistake or two in there.